# Can I use WebUtility.HtmlDecode to decode XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an XML-encoded attribute value. This is actually from a processing instruction. So the original data looks something like this:

```
<root><?pi key="value" data="&lt;foo attr=&quot;bar&quot;&gt;Hello world&lt;/foo&gt;" ?></root>
```

I can parse it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
                
public class Program
{
    private const string RawData = @"<root><?pi key=""value"" data=""&lt;foo attr=&quot;bar&quot;&gt;Hello world&lt;/foo&gt;"" ?></root>";

    public static void Main()
    {
        XDocument doc = GetXDocumentFromProcessingInstruction();
        IEnumerable<XElement> fooElements = doc.Descendants("foo");
        // ...
    }

    private static XProcessingInstruction LoadProcessingInstruction()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(rawData);
        return doc
                   .DescendantNodes()
                   .OfType<XProcessingInstruction>()
                   .First();
    }

    private static XDocument GetXDocumentFromProcessingInstruction()
    {
        XProcessingInstruction processingInstruction = LoadProcessingInstruction();
    
        // QUESTION:
        // Can there ever be a situation where HtmlDecode wouldn't decode the XML correctly?
        string decodedXml = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(processingInstruction.Data);

        // This works well, but it contains the attributes of the processing
        // instruction as text.
        string dummyXml = $"<dummy>{xml}</dummy>";
        return XDocument.Parse(dummyXml);
    }
```

This works absolutely fine, as far as I can tell.
But I am wondering if there might be some edge cases where it may fail, because of differences in how data would be encoded in XML vs. HTML.

Anybody have some more insight?

Edit:
Sorry, I made some incorrect assumptions about XProcessingInstruction.Data, but the code above was still working fine, so my question stands.
I have nonetheless rewritten my code and wrapped everything in an XElement, which (of course) removed the issue altogether:

```
    private static XDocument GetXDocumentFromProcessingInstruction2()
    {
        XProcessingInstruction processingInstruction = LoadProcessingInstruction();
    
        string encodedXml = string.Format("<dummy {0} />", processingInstruction.Data);
    
        XElement element = XElement.Parse(encodedXml);
    
        string parsedXml = element.Attribute("data").Value;

        return XDocument.Parse(parsedXml);
    }
```

So this does exactly what I need. But since WebUtility.HtmlDecode worked sufficiently well, I would still like to know if there could have been a situation where the first approach could have failed.

Comment: Is that XML or HTML? If XML can you show the whole document?

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: You do  not have valid xml.  The question marks are not valid.

Comment: @jdweng This is valid XML. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction

Comment: @TravelingFox : You cannot have processing instructions without a Root.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the question marks and adding a forward slash at end of your input I got this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "<pi data=\"&lt;foo attr=&quot;bar&quot;&gt;Hello world&lt;/foo&gt;\" />";
            XElement pi = XElement.Parse(input);
            string data = (string)pi.Attribute("data");
            XElement foo = XElement.Parse(data);
            string attr = (string)foo.Attribute("attr");
            string innertext = (string)foo;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for accidentally downvoting, you can edit your reply and I'll take the downvote back. This was actually helpful.